# styling text box with css

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I'm looking at a text boxes [here](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/). They have a very nice effect. How can I achieve same effect with CSS. This is what I'm able to get but it's not close to that.

***What I'm trying to achieve:***

*By default the textbox has greyish outline and when on focus it changes to blue color. I want a similar effect. I tried using outline property and shadows (in code below) but couldn't get that.*

My attempt to get that effect (https://jsfiddle.net/7jphmdzf/):

```css
#tags {
  width:500px;
  height:30px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
input:focus {
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.7pt blue; 
}
```

```html
<div class="ui-widget">
  <input id="tags">
</div>
```

Comment: What specific problem do you have?

Comment: i am trying to get input box like that but i couldn't get it what i could come up with ii have linked to jsfiddle but it looks way different.

Comment: @shaochuancs why the negative votes?

Comment: Even I'm also want to know, why the negative votes?

Comment: @anekix, "not close to that" is not specific enough to describe the problem. I think it is better to describe specific expected behaviour (I see the question is edited and this has been added), and what you have tried to achieve that expected behaviour.

Comment: @i realised quickly that my question was not specific and i also mentioned it immediately but before i had given a refrece and my attemp(code) to clone that refrence. i think the negative votes were not required. but thanks for help :)

Comment: As the specific expected behaviour and current attempt (outline property and shadows) is described, I'll withdraw my down vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following solution (https://jsfiddle.net/7jphmdzf/1/):

```css
#tags {
  outline:0;
  width:500px;
  height:30px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size:24px;
  padding:8px 12px;
}
#tags:focus {
  outline:0;
  border: 2px solid #0097cf;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ui-widget">
  <input id="tags" placeholder="Tags">
</div>
```

To change the color of the outline on `:focus` you have to set the `border`. There is no need for styling the `outline` or `box-shadow` of the `<input>`.

Answer (score 1):

Try This,

```css
#tags {

  width:200px;
  height:30px;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#tags:focus {
     outline: 0;
     border: 2px solid #109cdf;
}
```

```html
<div class="ui-widget">
  <input id="tags">
</div>
```